# CPLEX model, data seems to be correct, but when I run it I get the wrong answer

Tags: cplex, opl

I started learning OPL for a university project, to program the following model, and solve it given certain data. I've programmed it, as well as the data, but I'm not getting the answer I'm supposed to get, I'm not sure what's wrong.
[model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6ryq.png)
[data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTSNC.png)

I've read my data several times, and I'm sure every number is correct, so is it something to do with I've set up the matrices?
My .mod file is the folloiwng:

```
int n=...; //set of terminals
range N=1..n;

int t=...; //set of time periods
range T=1..t;

int v=...; //set of vehicles
range V=1..v;

range Np=1..n; range Vp=1..v;
   float p[Vp][Np][Np] =...; //p_vij
   
range Nc=1..n; range Vc=1..v;
   float c[Vc][Nc][Nc] =...; //c_vij
   
range Nd=1..n; range Td=1..t;
   float d[Td][Nd][Nd] =...; //d_tij

range Nm=1..n; range Tm=1..t; range Vm=1..v;
   int m[Vm][Nm][Tm] =...; //m_vit
   
range NA=1..n; range VA=1..v;
   int A[VA][NA][NA] =...; //A_vij
   
range Ntau=1..n;;
   int tau[Ntau][Ntau] =...; //
   
dvar boolean x[N][N][T][V]; //x_ijtv
dvar boolean y[N][N][T][V]; //y_ijtv

dexpr float f=sum(i in N,j in N:i!=j,t in T, v in V)(p[v][i][j]*x[i][j][t][v] - c[v][i][j]*y[i][j][t][v]);
   
maximize f;
subject to {
  forall(i in N, t in T, v in V:(t-1) in T)sum(j in N)(x[i][j][t][v] + y[i][j][t][v])- sum(k in N: k != i, t in T: t > tau[k][i])(x[k][i][t-tau[k][i]][v] + y[k][i][t-tau[k][i]][v])- y[i][i][t-1][v] == m[v][i][t]; // (2)

  forall(i in N, j in N, t in T)
    sum(v in V) x[i][j][t][v] <= d[t][i][j]; //(3)

  forall(i in N, j in N, t in T, v in V)
    A[v][i][j] == 0 => x[i][j][t][v] == 0 && y[i][j][t][v] == 0; //(4)

}
```

and my .dat file is:

```
n = 6;
t = 6;
v = 2;

c = \[\[  \[0 1 2 2 2 2\]
\[1 0 2 2 2 2\]
\[2 2 0 2 1 1\]
\[2 2 2 0 1 1\]
\[2 2 1 1 0 1\]
\[2 2 1 1 1 0\]\]

\[  \[0 3 3 2 2 2\]
\[3 0 3 3 2 2\]
\[3 3 0 1 2 2\]
\[2 3 1 0 3 3\]
\[2 2 2 3 0 3\]
\[2 2 2 3 3 0\]\]
\];

p = \[\[  \[0 1.8 3.6 3.6 3.6 3.6\]
\[1.8 0 3.6 3.6 3.6 3.6\]
\[3.6 3.6 0 3.6 1.8 1.8\]
\[3.6 3.6 3.6 0 3.6 3.6\]
\[3.6 3.6 1.8 3.6 0 1.8\]
\[3.6 3.6 1.8 3.6 1.8 0\]\]

\[  \[0 4.2 4.2 3.6 3.6 3.6\]
\[4.2 0 4.2 4.2 3.6 3.6\]
\[4.2 4.2 0 4.5 3.6 3.6\]
\[3.6 4.2 4.5 0 4.2 4.2\]
\[3.6 3.6 3.6 4.2 0 4.2\]
\[3.6 3.6 3.6 4.2 4.2 0\]\]
\];

d = \[\[\[0 0 0 0 0 0\]
\[0 0 0 0 0 0\]
\[0 0 0 0 0 0\]
\[0 0 0 0 0 0\]
\[0 0 0 0 0 0\]
\[0 0 0 0 0 0\]\]

\[\[0 0 0 0 0 0\]
\[0 0 0 0 0 0\]
\[0 0 0 0 0 0\]
\[0 3 0 0 0 0\]
\[0 0 0 0 0 1\]
\[0 0 0 0 0 0\]\]

\[\[0 0 0 0 0 0\]
\[0 0 3 0 0 0\]
\[0 0 0 0 0 0\]
\[0 0 0 0 0 0\]
\[0 0 0 0 0 0\]
\[0 0 0 0 0 0\]\]

\[\[0 0 0 0 0 0\]
\[0 0 0 0 0 0\]
\[0 0 0 0 0 0\]
\[0 0 0 0 0 0\]
\[0 0 0 0 0 0\]
\[0 0 0 0 0 0\]\]

\[\[0 0 0 0 0 0\]
\[0 0 0 0 0 0\]
\[0 0 0 0 0 0\]
\[0 0 0 0 0 0\]
\[2 0 0 0 0 0\]
\[0 0 0 0 0 0\]\]

\[\[0 0 0 0 0 0\]
\[0 0 0 0 0 0\]
\[0 0 0 0 0 0\]
\[0 0 0 0 0 0\]
\[0 0 0 0 0 0\]
\[0 0 0 0 0 0\]\]
\];

m = \[\[  \[0 0 0 0 0 0\]
\[0 0 0 0 0 0\]
\[0 0 0 0 0 0\]
\[0 0 0 0 0 0\]
\[0 0 0 0 0 0\]
\[1 0 0 0 0 0\]\]

\[  \[0 0 0 0 0 0\]
\[0 0 0 0 0 0\]
\[0 0 0 0 0 0\]
\[0 1 0 0 0 0\]
\[0 0 0 0 0 0\]
\[0 0 0 0 0 0\]\]
\];

A = \[\[  \[1 0 1 1 1 1\]
\[0 1 1 1 1 1\]
\[1 1 1 1 1 1\]
\[1 1 1 1 1 1\]
\[1 1 1 1 1 1\]
\[1 1 1 1 1 1\]\]

\[\[1 0 1 1 1 1\]
\[0 1 1 1 1 1\]
\[1 1 1 1 1 1\]
\[1 1 1 1 1 1\]
\[1 1 1 1 1 1\]
\[1 1 1 1 1 1\]\]
\];

tau =
\[\[1 2 1 1 1 2\]
\[2 1 2 1 2 3\]
\[1 2 1 1 3 2\]
\[1 1 1 1 1 3\]
\[1 2 3 1 1 1\]
\[2 3 2 3 1 1\]\];
```

When I run it, all the x values are 0 and some of the y values are 1. Given that data, I am supposed to get x5612=x5151=y6511=y6531=y1161=y5541=1, x4222=x2332=y3352=y3362=1, while the rest are 0.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to change

```
forall(i in N, t in T, v in V:(t-1) in T)sum(j in N)(x[i][j][t][v] + y[i][j][t][v])- 
sum(k in N: k != i, t in T: t > tau[k][i])(x[k][i][t-tau[k][i]][v] + y[k][i][t-tau[k][i]][v])- 
y[i][i][t-1][v] == m[v][i][t]; // (2)
```

into

```
forall(i in N, t in T, v in V:(t-1) in T)sum(j in N)(x[i][j][t][v] + y[i][j][t][v])- 
  sum(k in N: k != i, t in T: t > tau[k][i])(x[k][t-tau[k][i]][i][v] + y[k][t-tau[k][i]][i][v])-
   y[i][i][t-1][v] == m[v][i][t]; // (2)
```

?

This was not a good idea. You seem to be right.

Idea to debug your model.

Set your solution through

```
x[5][6][1][2]==1;
x[5][1][5][1]==1;
```

Turn your constraints to soft constraints

```
 forall(i in N, j in N, t in T)
    ct3:sum(v in V) x[i][j][t][v] <= d[t][i][j]; //(3)
```

You will get relaxations and then you can debug

[image: relaxation]

Comment: Hello! Why are you changing the x from x[k][i][t-tau[k][i]][v] to x[k][t-tau[k][i]][i][v]?
x is x[N][N][T][V], so I don't understand why you do that, because t-tau would be in T, not in N. It gives a different answer, but still not the right one :(

Comment: Indeed. I thought the indexes were wrong but they seem ok

Comment: So, do you see what else could be wrong? I'm not good at this at all, but I can't tell what it is. I think all the data is correct, so it should work.

Comment: if you are sure about your solution , you can write that in the model : x[5][6][1][2]==1;
x[5][1][5][1]==1; and then check why some constraints are ko. To make ct3 soft you can write forall(i in N, j in N, t in T)
    ct3:sum(v in V) x[i][j][t][v] <= d[t][i][j]+1; //(3)

Comment: okay, i will try to fix this, somehow. thanks for all your help!

Comment: can it have something to do with the (t-1) in T in (2)? it won't count when t=1 for the first sum, is there a way to fix that?

Comment: I think that the issue is more with values d in constraint 3

Comment: i've been testing the model around, with different data, and maybe the problem has to do with the m variable. i just ran the model, with vehicle 3 only being available at i=3 and t=3, but, in the solution, its being used at i=2 and t=1. but I also think there's something wrong with constraint (3), because the same vehicle is being used at the same time, but at different terminals. do you know how I could fix this?